# External properties file using Spring Boot and Docker

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

i cannot configure a Dockerfile for use external properties file with Spring Boot. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jre 
VOLUME /tmp /var/gpm/config
ADD gpm-web-1.0.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","/var/gpm/config","-Dspring.config.location=classpath:application.properties","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And in my host i have this path to properties file : /var/gpm/config/application.properties

But, don't works.

**UPDATE**

i change Dockerfile by this:

```
FROM java:8-jre
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gpm-web-1.0.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar","--spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties"]
```

And run with this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /opt/gpm/config/application.properties:/conf/application.properties --name gpm gpm-web:1.0
```

But, the file is take it like a folder:

```
root@b7349202b6d3:/# ls -la /conf/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 18 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 74 root root  4096 May 18 16:55 ..
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   40 May 18 16:43 application.properties
```

Comment: Have you bashed into the container when running and checked if the files are available in the volume?

Comment: Hi!, the folder it's mounted, but the folder is empty, cannot see the application.properties file.

Comment: Use docker inspect <container id> command and check the Mounts

Comment: i update this post, the inspect command shows: "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/opt/gpm/config/application.properties",
            "Destination": "/conf/application.properties",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }

Comment: ls -la /conf/ where did you execute it? so it seems to be available, you earlier said folder is empty

Comment: yes, but i've make some changes. And updates the info of this post.

Comment: file:/// instead of file:/ and rebuild you ur image.

Comment: Same problem. The application.properties file it's mounted like a directory and not like file: drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   40 May 18 16:43 application.properties

Comment: -v /opt/gpm/config:/conf, I have always mounted folders.. not sure it makes a difference in ur case

Comment: From docker documentation "A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System. Data volumes provide several useful features for persistent or shared data"... I don't think files are supported.

Comment: @Shibashis finally works!! .. the problem was the permissions of file. Now can see the file in the container.

Comment: good that worked. But I am confused how it got fixed, from the earlier inspect command output it looks like the permissions were there already

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to mount the volume to the conf folder e.g.

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /opt/gpm/config:/conf --name gpm gpm-web:1.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem is about permissions of the file to be mounted in Docker container. Docker creates a directory if the original file is not found in host.

Thanks to @Shibashis for the help.